# Setting environment variables for Gnome on Wayland session only

Tags: bash, gnome, gtk, wayland

I'm testing GNOME 3.14 on Wayland on ArchLinux and I would also like to test GTK+ on Wayland.
To do so, I can set the following two env variables from terminal

```
export GDK_BACKEND=wayland CLUTTER_BACKEND=wayland
```

anf then run my app (i.e. nautilus) from terminal too.
However I would like to set this session-wide so that I don't have to launch my apps from terminal.
I think I cannot set them on `.bashrc` because they will break my standard GNOME on X session.

So where is the proper place to set those variables for GNOME on Wayland session ONLY?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403196/23305 for setting session-wide environment variables under Gnome Wayland. In short, `~/.config/environment.d/`. That said, I'm not sure there's a way to _conditionally_ set variables. There is `${:-}` and `${:+}` substitution syntax that might be able help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a way to do this.

Create (if necessary) a `~/.profile` file and add the following:

```
WAY=$(ps -aux | head -n -1 | grep "/usr/bin/gnome-shell --wayland")

if [ -z "$WAY" ]; then
    echo X11
else
    export GDK_BACKEND=wayland
    export CLUTTER_BACKEND=wayland
fi
```

Logout and then login in your favorite session (either X or Wayland).
By using looking glass you can check if your application is actually running on Wayland. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233459/real-gnome-wayland-session).

Comment: possible pitfall: Wayland usually doesn't read `~/.profile`, see https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/SessionStart

Comment: Wayland doesn't source .profile so this can be correct. It needs to be untagged as the Answer.