# Real GNOME Wayland session

Tags: bash, gnome, wayland

I'm trying to test a "real" wayland gnome session. I know that not all applications can run on Wayland natively (for this we have XWayland) but at least I would like to have GTK+ applications to do so.

So, I created a `~/.profile` file containing

```
export GDK_BACKEND=wayland
export CLUTTER_BACKEND=wayland
```

**>>> Edit**: instead of contents above, you may add this to `~/.profile` in order to make it work for both X and Wayland sessions:

```
WAY=$(ps -aux | head -n -1 | grep "/usr/bin/gnome-shell --wayland")

if [ -z "$WAY" ]; then
    echo X11
else
    export GDK_BACKEND=wayland
    export CLUTTER_BACKEND=wayland
fi
```

**<<<**

Then from my GDM login screen (Archlinux) I select gnome on wayland.

Once ready, I start (for example) nautilus (normally from the dash, not from terminal), then I open looking glass, I select "windows" section and I click on nautilus window and I get `GType:MetaWindowWayland` which tells me that Nautilus is actually running on Wayland instead of XWayland. Super!

[image: GType:MetaWindowWayland]

However, if, again from looking glass, I select gnome-sell entry, I get `GType:MetaWindowX11` telling me that the shell is running on XWayland.

[image: GType:MetaWindowX11]

Mutter seems to be running on Wayland (as for example the clipboard between X and W still does not work), all the GTK+ app that I launch after login are running on Wayland too (`GType:MetaWindowWayland`) however gnome-shell is still on X11.

My guess is that gnome-shell does not take into consideration `~/.profile` while starting the session. Maybe because it is started by the system not by the user?
So maybe I have to add

```
export GDK_BACKEND=wayland
export CLUTTER_BACKEND=wayland
```

somewhere else?

Comment: I think that's just the fake X11 root window created by gnome-shell to support XWayland clients.

Answer (score 2):

The `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile` and similar files get only sourced if a shell which supports them is started.

In turn only if such a shell is used to launch programs will the the environment variables propagate to the newly launched program.

But there is no reason a program launcher must launch a program through a shell sourcing any of this file.

Especially many modern program launchers launch programs through systemd (user slices), as far as I know this involves Gnome.

There are a bunch or reasons why this makes sense but I won't go into it, as it's off topic.

**As far as I know on modern Linux system the only reliable way to set environment variables is through environment.d.**

Some places will also recommend PAM env to you, but that this works is more a unintended side effect then a meant feature and should be avoided and might stop working in the future.

For this create a environment.d config file:

`.config/environment.d/user-vars.conf`

In it, set the environment variables, e.g.:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
CLUTTER_BACKEND=wayland
#Makes some games not work, better to run them through XWayland
#SDL_VIDEODRIVER=wayland
ECORE_EVAS_ENGINE=wayland_egl
ELM_ENGINE=wayland_egl
```

You can use `systemctl --user show-environment` to see all environment variables a new launched applications will have.

See `man environment.d`.

The only major drawback is that I have no idea how to "in-session reload" environment.d so that changes get applied to newly started programs. So for changes
to take affect you need to restart your session (i.e. **fully** log out and log in again or login on a new TTY, not just pause your user session).

If I find a way to do so I will post it here.

---

PS:
I have a bit of a funky system where some, but not all programs are launched through systemd. This shouldn't apply to you (as you run Gnome). But if anyone has the same problem I solved it by including `export $(systemctl --user show-environment)` in my `.bash_profile`. But you should not need to to it if you don't have a very "hacked together" system.

Comment: You can reload specific variables by using `systemctl import-environment`.

E.g. `export FOO=12;`, `systemctl --user import-environment FOO`.

Comment: Also not that on I don't mean that the only reliable way is environment.d because systemd messed things up, but because before environment.d *there simple was no reliable way*.
Even before it, program launchers might not have sourced `.profile` and similar. And pam_env being usable for it was kinda an accident and even lead to some security problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add that to `.bashrc` which also works for non-login shells.

Answer (score 1):

Too late answer but this is under `"unanswered questions"`, clearing up.

> GDK_BACKEND=wayland

is sufficient if you start applications from Terminal inside wayland gnome session.

You can start gnome-shell via tty:

> gnome-shell --wayland --display_server

If you already have a running instance you should prefix the command with dbus-run-session:

> dbus-run-session gnome-shell --wayland --display_server

All recent versions of Fedora are wayland by default.