# Manually start a target?

Tags: systemd

I'm using `systemctl --user` for a lot of user services on my Linux desktop.

One of the things I'm doing (per "[Starting A DBus Session Application from systemd User Mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368730/)") as a hack to get my environment variables from my session is that I'm running a manual script on startup of the graphical session which calls `systemctl --user import-environment`. I then have a dummy service which I start via `systemctl --user start environment.service`. All of my other services which are enabled depend on `environment.service`.

I figure this would probably make a better target than a service. Is there a way to create a target which must be explicitly started via `systemctl --user start user-login-graphical.target`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just fix your session so you didn't have to employ bizarre hacks?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with my session. systemd by default strips out environment variables and so the only way for me to get them into the environment is via the import-environment command.

Comment: Err, no. Not at all.

Comment: Feel free to disagree with the facts: variables from my graphical session are not imported into systemd userspace units. If I use show-environment, I can see only four or five environment variables. After import, it's closer to 20. I want to be able to launch things in my desktop session from systemd.

Comment: Like I said above, *fix your broken session*. It's not a systemd issue.

Comment: I don't see this as a bug. Why should the systemd user session inherit environment variables from the graphical session? The systemd user session is not dependent on any graphical session.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to accomplish this via the following unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=User Graphical Login
Requires=default.target
After=default.target
```

I will then manually start the target as it has no `Install` section and will not get started on its own.

```
systemctl --user start user-graphical-login.target
```

Comment: Done and done .

Comment: Thumbs up for how you manage your session!  Been doing exactly the same stuff for years as well... `;)`

Comment: This does not work anymore. I am getting the following error: "Service has no ExecStart=, ExecStop=, or SuccessAction=. Refusing."