# How to set an environment variable for all users of the system under Debian only when running Wayland?

Tags: debian, environment-variables, wayland

I’d like to set an environment variable, for every users, when running Gnome under Wayland. The variable should not be set when running Gnome under X11. For concreteness, say I want to set the variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` to the value `wayland` when running Wayland.

I tried putting `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` in `/usr/share/gdm/env.d/wayland-env` (following the [doc](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/SessionStart) mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326161)) (hoping this would have an effect only under Wayland) but this seems to have no effect, even under Wayland: after rebooting, logging under Gnome / Wayland, opening a terminal: `echo $QT_QPA_PLATFORM` yields nothing.

I use a freshly installed Debian Bullseye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **should**  work under debian:

You can create a simple script that determines whether or not the machine is running under X11 or Wayland:

```
loginctl show-session "$XDG_SESSION_ID" -p Type --value
```

Can return either `X11` or `Wayland` (It can also return `tty`)

Therefore:

```bash
if [[ $(loginctl show-session "$XDG_SESSION_ID" -p Type --value) = 'wayland' ]]; then
    export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
fi
```

You can also just check whether or not your session uses `$DISPLAY` or `$WAYLAND_DISPLAY` as one of its environment variables.

On bash, you can can place scripts you wish all users to execute after login in `/etc/profile.d`. Don't forget to make it executable and make sure it has an extension `.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a discussion about [systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6414) that lead me to a possible answer. (Sorry for answering my own question.)

Which files are executed under what conditions exactly at start is still unclear to me, but on my system at least, the file `/etc/profile` seems to be executed when starting Gnome (including when running Wayland). It executes in turn the files under `/etc/profile.d/`. Taking example on the file [`im-config_wayland.sh`](https://salsa.debian.org/input-method-team/im-config/-/blob/devel/im-config_wayland.sh), I have created a file `/etc/profile.d/wayland.sh` that sets the environment variables I want conditionally, depending on whether Wayland is ran. Here is its content.

```bsh
test "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = 'wayland' || return
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
```

I suspect that more elegant solutions exist, for example, that would not set these variables when running non-graphical shells. But at least, this approach solves my concrete problem for now…